# How to group items by category using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
    function category_array() {
        var send_array = Array();
        var send_cnt = 0;
        var chkbox = $('input[name="category[]"]:checked');

        for(i=0;i<chkbox.length;i++) {
                if (chkbox[i].checked == true){
                        send_array[send_cnt] = chkbox[i].value;
                        send_cnt++;
                }
        }

        console.log(send_array);
        $("#category_list").val(send_array);
    }
```

current result is:

```
 ['men_a', 'men_b', 'mem_c', 'woman_a', 'woman_d']
```

Desired result is:

```
 {men: [a,b,c], women: [a,d]}
```

Comment: Do you mean a string like `"men[a,b,c]"`? Or do you want nested arrays? What you showed is not valid syntax for arrays.

Comment: Or maybe `{men: [a,b,c], women: [a,d]}` ?

Comment: There's no use of `split()` in the question, what does the title mean?

Comment: You don't need to test `.checked`, since you used the `:checked` selector.

Comment: You can use `let [gender, item] = chkbox[i].value.split('_');`

Comment: BTW, don't forget to declare the `i` variable as a local variable. I've seen lots of bugs due to nested functions that both use the same iteration variable with declaring it.

Comment: If you want an object, why did you create it as an array?

Comment: Sorry I am noobie

Comment: let [gender, item] = chkbox[i].value.split('_');
Can you tell me please where I put that code?

Comment: `{men: [a,b,c], women: [a,d]}` is only valid JS if a,b,c,d are actual variables defined in  the same scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loop over `arr`, and get `gendre` and its `value` and add them to the first `res` variable if *gendre is male* else to *second*.

```js
const arr = ["men_a", "men_b", "mem_c", "woman_a", "woman_d"];
const res = [[], []];
for (person of arr) {
  const [gendre, value] = person.split("_");
  if (gendre == "men") res[0].push(value);
  else res[1].push(value);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // [["a","b"],["c","a","d"]]
```

Update to store values in ***an object*** instead of ***an array***

```js
const arr = ["men_a", "men_b", "mem_c", "woman_a", "woman_d"];
const res = {'men':[],'women':[]};
for (person of arr) {
  const [gendre, value] = person.split("_");
  if (gendre == "men") res['men'].push(value);
  else res['women'].push(value);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // {"men":["a","b"],"women":["c","a","d"]}
```

Comment: Please consider the updated question. OP requires an object instead of an array.

Comment: Ok I'll update it now...

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `send_array` as an object, not an array.

Then split the value at the `_` character, and use the first part as the object key, and push the second part into the array at that key.

```js
function category_array() {
  var send_array = {};
  var chkbox = $('input[name="category[]"]:checked');
  chkbox.each((i, box) => {
    let [gender, item] = box.value.split('_');
    if (send_array[gender]) {
      send_array[gender].push(item);
    } else {
      send_array[gender] = [item];
    }
  });

  console.log(send_array);
  $("#category_list").val(JSON.stringify(send_array));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Men A <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="men_a">
Men B <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="men_b">
Men C <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="men_c">
Men D <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="men_d">
<br>
Women A <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="women_a">
Women B <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="women_b">
Women C <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="women_c">
Women D <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="women_d">

<input type="text" id="category_list">

<button type="button" onclick="category_array()">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

See comments in the code:

```
function category_array() {
    var send_array = {};
    var chkbox = $('input[name="category[]"]:checked');

    for(i=0;i<chkbox.length;i++) {
           // no need to check that it's checked, you already checked that (in the selector)
           const [gender,val] = chkbox[i].value.split("_"); // assuming input is always valid here (it won't be
           send_array[gender] = send_array[gender] || [] // make sure it exists
           send_array[gender].push(val) // add the new value
    }

    console.log(send_array);
    $("#category_list").val(JSON.stringify(send_array)); // you can't assign an object as a node's value
}
```